# has_one association doesn't return nil after calling destroy on associated object

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Naively, if my model `Foo` has

```
has_one associated_object
```

I would expect

```
some_foo.associated_object.destroy
some_foo.associated_object
```

to return `nil`. However, it still returns the associated object (with the `destroyed` flag set).

In the database, the `associated_object` table row has been removed, so if I load a second `Foo` model object for the same record, I get the `nil` I'm looking for:

```
Foo.find(some_foo.id).associated_object
# => nil
```

Is there a way I can declare the ActiveRecord `has_one` relation such that I'll get `nil` for in-memory `Foo` model, without having to check the `destroyed` flag on the associated object?

---

**ETA:** In case it wasn't clear, I'm not looking for an *additional* call to make, *after* I call `destroy`. I'm looking for how to make a `has_one` relationship behave as conveniently and transparently as `has_many`:

```
some_foo.many_objects.each(&:destroy)
# ... other code, not knowing about the earlier 'destroy' call(s)
some_foo.many_objects.empty?
# => true
```

Comment: You have to call `reload` to refresh the im-memory state

Comment: Which means you have to know to call `reload` on the parent object even if the child object has been passed to some completely different piece of code to be `destroyed`? If you can do that, you might as well just explicitly set the field to `nil`, and anyway there must be a better way.

Comment: Hey @DavidMoles, I'm having the same issue even on the latest rails. Is this the intended behaviour? Seems bizarre.

Comment: @TonyDaly seems to be? I never bothered to dig into the code to find out. 

Comment: It is default behavior, but I would disagree with setting it to nil if you want callbacks triggered. Calling destroy triggers any callbacks defined on the model.